# Is "Display size" option not present on tablets?

Tags: settings, 7.1-nougat

I recently bought Lenovo Tab4 8 plus. It runs Andoird Naugat. I have Nexus 6. I love content dense screen. So on my Nexus 6, I always keep font size and display size to the least. (More on this [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/268754/how-to-change-the-size-of-text-icons-and-more-in-android-nougat/)). I can find font size option in my tablet, but I cannot find the display size option on tablet, as can be seen in below screen shot:
It can be found below Font size option in Nexus 6 Naugat.

[image]

Is this lenovo made customization / screw-up thing, or there is some reason for it? and way to enable it? Any third party app to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Does both of them have same Android OS? Like AOSP or else?
My suspect is the setting based on Official ROM. In this case the Nexus 6 use 'Display Size' to adjust DPI, it adjust font size to match DPI means larger DPI smaller font or as you wish.
In Lenovo you get fixed DPI but you can adjust only font size.
Hope it helps

Comment: Both are running Naugat that came from company. I never played with rooting and flashing custom ROMs. Nexus 6 is obviously stock Naugat. For details. **(1)** Lenovo Tab: Android 7.1.1, Security patch: Aug 1, 2017, Software version: TB-8704x_RF01_170519, Build number: TB-8704x_S000029_170901_ROW  **(2)** Nexus 6: Android 7.1.1, Security patch: Oct 5, 2017, Build number: N6F27M I checked the dpi modification apps, but most require root access. Is there any which work without root and is safe?